# Can two different pairs of RSA key have the same modulus?

Tags: cryptanalysis, rsa, public-key

Can $n=pq$ be part of two different pairs of RSA keys?

If such keys exist, say $(e_1,n)$ and $(e_2,n)$, how are they related? 
What will be the security concerns for the two users?

Comment: I edited your comment to have $e_1$ and $e_2$ instead of $e_1$ twice. If that was not your intention, feel free to fix.

Comment: Related to your question is whether then moduli of different public keys should be coprime (they should!!), but in real life this is sometimes not the case, see https://freedom-to-tinker.com/blog/nadiah/new-research-theres-no-need-panic-over-factorable-keys-just-mind-your-ps-and-qs/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The users will be able to read each other's messages (even though they can have different private keys, say $d_1$ and $d_2$). This is because knowledge of $d_i$ is sufficient to factor $N$, thus allowing that party to compute the other party's private key. This was detailed by Boneh in his analysis of [RSA attacks](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf#page=4).

Answer (score 15):

Two properties of RSA are important here:

- If you know $p$ and $q$, you can reverse RSA encryption for arbitrary $e$
- If you know $e$, $d$ and $n$ you can efficiently factor $n$, and obtain $p$ and $q$.

This means if you know one private key for a given $n$, you know all of them. Thus different persons should not share a modulus.

Such a scheme can be useful if one person needs multiple public keys. This person can use multiple $e$s with a shared $n$. There are few restrictions on the choice of $e$s, for example $ e_3 = e_1 * e_2 $ is broken.

Such key pairs are only useful in very specific scenarios. For example some blind signature schemes use different values of $e$ with shared $n$ to sign different currency denominations.